# change color of first div within another div, with an h2 in between

Tags: html, css

I notice that in the following code:

```
<div id="test1">
    <div>1Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div>2Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
#test1 div:first-child{
    color:red;
}
```

The first div (1Lorem...) will be displayed red, but if I change the html to this:

```
<div id="test1">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

The first div will no longer display red.  Can anyone please advise me how to make that first div (1Lorem...) display in red while keeping the h2?  I have to keep that h2 there, and I really need to use a method where this first-child div will be changed to red.

Comment: `#test1 div:first-of-type``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#test1 div:first-child` only selects a div that is **also** the first child

`#test1 div:first-of-type` will select the first div within `'test1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:first-of-type` or `:nth-of-type(1)`:

```
#test1 div:first-of-type{
    color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PLKEG/)**